# Distance between point and arc

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Knowns:

- $c$ = center of rotation for arc
- $\theta$ = arc angle
- $r$ = radius of arc
- $R$ = some constant threshold
- 2 dimensions
- Arc always swept out from the origin.
- $P$ = some arbitrary point.

I need to calculate the shortest distance from some arbitrary point with respect to two arcs : $ (r - R) \theta$ and $(r + R) \theta$, such that the distance returned is the closest distance of the point from either of these arcs.

Excuse the poor drawing, I'm not well versed in the digital tools to illustrate the problem, but my preview seems clear.

I can think of a way involving discretizing the two arcs into points, and taking the distance of the point to each of those discrete points, taking the minimum of those distances, and then taking the minimum of the two minimum distances of the point from the two arcs, but this is an approximate solution, and I am looking for an exact solution.

What is the general exact solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: I really can't get what you are asking...

Comment: @HCP16 Find the shortest distance $d$ of point $P$ from the pair of arcs defined by center = $c$, radius = $r \pm R$, angle = $\theta$.

Comment: Are you asking the shortest distance to any arc or to the curved rectangle they define ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the arcs are concentric, I would translate $c$ and $P$ such that $c\to 0$ and $P\to P'$. Then $d=\min(||P'|-(r-R)|,||P'|-(r+R)|).$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question: Wouldn't this only work in the case where $P$ is located somewhere within the bounds of the arc and x axis such that there exist a radius line that can be extended through  $P$? if the point was located some arbitrary position not within the area bounded by the arc, doesn't this fall apart?

Comment: Wait, never mind, in this case, $(r - R)$ and $(r + R)$ is the distance of ALL points that lie on the arc from the origin, and $|P'|$ would be the distance of the point from the origin. This is brilliant, thank you.

Comment: I can draw a diagram where changing theta would change the result, but I don't see theta in the answer, so I clearly misunderstand either the question or the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let

- $\phi$ be the angle of $P$ from $c$, where $0$ is straight down and with the same orientation as $\theta$, so we can compare them.
- $r_p = |P-c|$ (that is, the dist of $P$ from $c$),
- $E = (r\sin\theta,r(1-\cos\theta))$ be the endpoint of the arc,

Then I believe
$\quad\phi < \theta \quad\Rightarrow\quad d = \min\ \big(|r_p - r + R|,|r_p - r-R|\big)$ (as [Adrian Keister](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2671081) answered),
$\quad$else
$\quad\quad\quad\quad \ d = \min\ \big(|P-(0,0)|,\ |P-E|\big)$